# Why is fstream reading 0 from a file?

Tags: c++

I am having a slight issue when reading from a file in C++, the reason for the function is to find a line that has the characters v and a space at the beginning of it.

It is finding line correctly, but when trying read numbers from the file, it is always outputting 0.

Here is the code for the function

```
Model::Model(std::string fileName) {
    std::ifstream reader;

    reader.open(fileName);

    float temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0, temp3 = 0;

    if (reader.is_open()) {
        std::string line;

        while (reader.eof() != true) {
            getline(reader, line);

            if (line.substr(0, 2) == "v ") {
                reader >> temp1 >> temp2 >> temp3;

                std::cout << temp1 << " | " << temp2 << " | " << temp3 << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Error opening the file at path " + fileName;
    }
}
```

It is reading from the file fine, and is printing all well, but the temp variables are staying at 0 for some reason.

Anyone know how to fix this? Or any ideas as to why this is happening?

My only idea is that the stream for some reason is getting bad input, but that wouldn't make too much sense.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Relevant read: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: It would help to show a sample of the input file

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert each read character to integer. So add the following temporary variables:

```cpp
char temp1_char, temp2_char, temp3_char;
```

and do:

```cpp
reader >> temp1_char>> temp2_char>> temp3_char;
temp1 = (temp1_char- '0' ) % 48;
temp2 = (temp2_char- '0') % 48;
temp3 = (temp3_char- '0') % 48;
std::cout << temp1 << " | " << temp2 << " | " << temp3 << std::endl;
```

Also, try replacing:

```cpp
while (reader.eof() != true)
```

with:

```cpp
while (getline(reader, line))
```

You didn't mention how the file that you want to read from is structured. Provide a snippet from the file showing some lines containing `"v "` and what you want to be stored in `temp1`, `temp2` and `temp3`. And provide some lines where the condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `getline(reader, line)` extracts a line of input from `reader` and places it into `line`.  Then, when a line of input meets your condition, it proceeds to extract further input from `reader`.  However, the extraction continues at the next line.  And, so attempting `reader >> temp1 >> temp2 >> temp3` fails.  As a result, any and all subsequent attempts to extract data will fail.

I would suggest using `std::stringstream` together with `std::getline` to parse your line of input.  For example, first use `getline(reader, line)` to get your line of input into `line`. Then, if it meets your condition, store the string into the string stream.  Then extract the string from the string stream into variables.

By the way, as others have already suggested, you can use `getline(reader, line)` as your condition for your while loop. The returned stream is converted to True when successful.  Otherwise, it is converted to False.

```
Model::Model(std::string fileName) {

    std::ifstream reader;
    reader.open(fileName);

    if (reader.is_open()) {

        float temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0, temp3 = 0;
        std::string temp, line;
        std::stringstream ss;

        while (std::getline(reader, line)) {
            if (line.substr(0, 2) == "v ") {
                ss << line;
                ss >> temp >> temp1 >> temp2 >> temp3;
                std::cout << temp1 << " | " << temp2 << " | " << temp3 << std::endl;
                ss.clear();
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Error opening the file at path " + fileName;
    }
}
```